# Null Pointer Exception in Kotlin for non primitive items. Why?

Tags: kotlin, oop

```
open class Vehicle {    
    inner class Engine {
        var specs: String = ""
        constructor() {
            specs = getSpecs()
        }
    }
    val engine = Engine()
    open fun getSpecs(): String {
        return ""
    }
}
class Bike: Vehicle() {
    private val model: Model = Model("APACHE", "YAMAHA")
    private val year = 2024
    override fun getSpecs(): String {
        return "Model: ${model.company} - ${model.modelName}. Year: $year"
    }
}
data class Model(
    val modelName: String,
    val company: String
)
```

The above code throws an Null Pointer Exception when I create a object of Bike class.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
> invoke "Model.getCompany()" because "this.model" is null

I do understand why the exception is called.

What I don't understand is that when I remove the ***model.company*** and ***model.modelName*** (When I don't call any class other than primitive types) inside getSpecs method, it works fine.

I don't know why that happens, Shouldn't it also throw an exception when I try to get year variable since it is also not initialized?

Comment: Year is a primitive int, so it is 0 when it is unitialized. If you specify its type has `val year: Int?`, then it will probably get boxed and throw an NPE.

Comment: You say you understand why the exception is thrown, but it seems like do not. The exception is because `model` is null. `year` is not null, so of course there is no exception when you print `year`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, classes that correspond with Java primitives are not actually compiled as classes if you make them non-nullable. So the uninitialized version of an `Int` is `0` rather than null.

If the property was declared with the type `Int?`, then the uninitialized value would be null. However, using a nullable in a String is acceptable and it will simply put the text "null" in the String rather than throwing a NPE.

Maybe you already realize this, but you should never call an open function or property from the constructor because it can create this kind of runtime error. It exposes inner workings of Kotlin that you normally do not need to know about to avoid invalid states and have null safety.

Comment: No you would not get an NPE if year was null. It's only used in the string as `"$year"` which would simply result in the string `"null"`.

Comment: @k314159 Good point. I’ll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Superclass constructor is called before the Bike constructor.  Vehicule calls getSpecs in its constructor, which is overriden in the Bike class requires a model which doesn't exist yet in the Bike class.